# plotting percentage of occurrence in a group in data frame python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with two columns, age group and gender.
I want to plot the percentage of females and males in every age group.

this is what i did

```
df.groupby('AGE_B_M0')['Gender_Type_Cd_M0'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

how do i plot this as pie chart ?

I got the percentages correctly but i want to plot the percentage of genders in all age groups.

for example : females 30% and males 70% in age group 18-25  etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.groupby('Gender_Type_Cd_M0').count() / len(df)` should return the percentage of observations for each gender.